# WorkbookFactory cannot be resolved (Selenium/maven/java )

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

I am using a utility class which reads the data from .xlsx file but i am getting error for the "import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;" and for book=WorkbookFactory.create(file);

I have tried adding various maven dependencies to the project and updated the project again and again but nothing seems to work

```
package com.crm.qa.util;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;


import com.crm.qa.base.Base;

public class Testutil extends Base{

    //declare page load and implicit wait values and load them in base class

    public static long PAGE_LOAD_TIMEOUT =20;
    public static long IMPLICIT_WAIT=10;

    //for testdata
    static Workbook book;
    static Sheet sheet;

    public static String TEST_DATA_SHEET_PATH="D:\\Selenium\\CRMAutomation\\CRM-Master\\CRMQA\\src\\main\\java\\com\\crm\\qa\\testdata\\CRMTestdata.xlsx";

    //for switching to mainpanel frame
    public void switchtoframe() {
        driver.switchTo().frame("mainpanel");
    }

    //for reading testdata
    public Object[][] getTestData(String sheetname) {

        FileInputStream file=null;
        try {
            file=new FileInputStream(TEST_DATA_SHEET_PATH);
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            book=WorkbookFactory.create(file);
        }catch(InvalidFormatException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        sheet=book.getSheet(sheetname);

        //used two dimensional object array
        Object[][] data= new Object[sheet.getLastRowNum()][sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum()];
        for(int i=0;i<sheet.getLastRowNum();i++) {
            for(int k=0;k<sheet.getRow(i+1).getLastCellNum();k++) {
                data[i][k]=sheet.getRow(i+1).getCell(k).toString();

            }
        }

        return data;
    }

}
```

I am expecting that script should read the values from .xlsx file.
I am new to forum if anything wrong kindly guide me for editing the question.

Comment: Please add your pom.xml file here

Comment: Up to `apache poi 3.17` `WorkbookFactory` was shipped in `poi-ooxml`. Since `apache poi 4.0.0` it is in `poi`.

Comment: @AxelRichter Thank you. Apache poi-ooxml 4.0.0 solved the problem. Thanks again.

Comment: I would recommend using latest stable `apache poi 4.0.1` then.

Comment: Sure will do that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Updated with poi-ooxml 4.0.0 Now working fine